# Unable to generate rails controller: mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mysql2

I am new to RoR and as much as they warned me about not using OSX to setup my application (because of these kind of problems), here I am. running OS X 10.82 and I have tried everything in an attempt to successfully bundle all the packages and keep everything coherent i.e. Homebrew, RVM, gem updates, bundler etc

My problem seems to be specifically with MySQL and mysql2. I tried some other stuff with a Rails application not running mysql and never had any of these problems.

> /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)

I do have access to `mysql -u root -p`

Is this related to doing or not doing: "sudo commands" during the installation process?

- ruby 2.0.0p0  [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
- Rails 3.2.13
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.10, for osx10.8 (x86_64)

Comment: I have since entered the application specific database.yml file , which was configured to use the MySQL root user by default but no password was assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I have since entered the application specific database.yml file , which was configured to use the MySQL root user by default but no password was assigned.

-THIS IS HOW DATABASE.YML LOOKED

- MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
- Install the MYSQL driver
- gem install mysql2
- Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile

-#   gem 'mysql2'

-#

-# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:

-#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html

development:

adapter: mysql2

encoding: utf8

reconnect: false

database: simple_cms

pool: 5

username: root

password: addedmypasswordhere (please not this is sensitive to spaces. You should only have one space after "pasword:"

socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

I am not sure if this solves the problem entirely since for me it fixed this error but now I am seeing others:

Now when I do $ rails generate (which should just be a help menu) I get the following (which may be an issue of its own):

/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Unknown database 'simple_cms_development' (Mysql2::Error)

Update:

In general I was doing this simple_cms using a Lynda.com tutorial. Key point is that it seems that in 2010 (when tutorial was made) you could use the command $ rails generate without having a database created or configured. The reason I say this is because once I moved along the tutorial (after ignoring the problem I was having). The tutorial guides you in creating the above-mentioned simple_cms_development database and setting the information for user and password in the database.yml file.

After having done that I was able to run the $ rails generate command and even create a migration without any problems.

So after much trouble, it appears to me that this is all related to the apparently "new requirement" of having the development database setup before calling a rails command like I have discussed because it makes a call to that database that will give you and error even when you are just creating a controller that doesn't requires your database to be ready yet. I think that was the assumption that was done by the tutorial.

Please let me know if you have any additional input on this issue.